# Asus Pen on ZenBook Flip 14 UM462DA

Tags: asus, stylus, doubleclick

I recently bought a ZenBook Flip 14 UM462DA which I put Ubuntu 20.04 on. Now my problem is with the Asus pen. It works somewhat fine for taking notes in Xournal++, which was my original goal but I've noticed that it randomly double-clicks when I touch the screen only once. That makes using the ZenBook in tablet mode with the pen extremely tedious.
I've been searching for a solution for a good few hours but I can't seem to get anywhere.
Here's the xinput props for the pen, I hope that's useful. If you need anything else please let me know.

> Device 'ELAN9008:00 04F3:290F Pen (0)':
> Device Enabled (149):   1
> Coordinate Transformation Matrix (151): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
> Device Node (275):      "/dev/input/event18"
> Device Product ID (276):        1267, 10511
> libinput Tablet Tool Pressurecurve (652):       0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000, 1.000000

Comment: It is not very clear to me what your actual problem is, but Xournal++ has an option to disable accidental touch, if that's what you are looking for.

**Edit -> Preferences -> Touchscreen -> Hand Recognition**

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi I worded that weirdly, sorry. It seems to me that touching the screen with my Asus pen in general is sometimes interpreted as a double click when it should only be a single click. It would've been a lot clearer if I left out the part about Xournal++.

Comment: Were there any other issues with using Ubuntu on this model? (loud fans, screen brightness, sound ...)